# find all renault garages in France

Tags: data-request, geospatial, transportation

I need to have all the addresses of Car-dealer [occasion] and mechanics
in France.

How to achieve this - how to obtain the data?

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name","addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street","addr:housenumber","website"," contact:email=*")][timeout:300];
area[name="France , Allemagne etc... "]->.a;
( node(area.a)[amenity=Car occasion - Renault];
  way(area.a)[amenity=Car occasion - Renault];
  rel(area.a)[amenity=Car occasion - Renault];);
out;
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ask https://www.renault.fr/contact.html?

Comment: hello  - i try to do so -... but i guess that it would be a good task to do so and to ask here

Comment: btw - a output in CSV would be very very interesting...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the data in [OpenStreetMaps](http://osm.org/) from the [overpass-turbo.eu](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) API. [Here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:shop%3Dcar) are details for `shop=car`.

[image]

([sample results](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/htO))

You can use the data-tab to see the underlying data

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 705403313,
  "lat": 48.8309582,
  "lon": 2.2358227,
  "tags": {
    "addr:housenumber": "577",
    "addr:street": "Avenue du Général Leclerc",
    "name": "Renault",
    "operator": "Renault",
    "shop": "car"
  }
},
```

I'm not so good with the API so maybe someone who knows it can better make a query, for example:

- brand=renault
- service=dealer;repair
- shop=car_repair

Comment: hello dear philishem - thanks alot - that looks graeat

Comment: hello philshem - many many thanks all looks great  one question i have; although you did not enter any bbox-data the system took a part of paris for the results - why is this so!? Guess that we allways have to enter a sort of bbox-data that is corresponding to an area. BTW - what if i want to have the whole france in the bbox - how to achieve that!?.... Love to hear from you

Comment: very interesting that without the entry of bbbox you have results centered in FRANCE - why is this so!? btw - a output in CSV would be very very interesting...

Comment: Hi @dlibert - I don't know enough about OSM or Overpass to really help anymore. If this is a useful resource but you aren't sure how to use it, I'd close this question and post a new one (that links to this one). For CSV see the [Output CSV section](wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL) of the documentation.